# Alternative way to compressing files for web page speed

Tags: javascript, html, web, compression, gzip

I ran my website through `Google's Page Speed Insights` and compressing my javascript files is apparently a priority. I am hosting on Go Daddy and am not sure if it is enabled, so I would  like to find an alternative.

I came across a blog post stating that you could compress the files locally on the command line with `gzip file.js`. But then how does the browser reference and unzip these files? It would be great to get a step by step process. An example of a file that would need to be compressed would be `http://mydomain.es/jquery-ui.js`.

In other words, once I have compressed `jquery-ui.js.gz` what do I do with it? Okay, I upload it to the server, but then what? Do I refer to it in my html as `<script src="jquery-ui.min.js.gz"></script>` How does the browser know to unzip it and where to find it?

Comment: This can help, if you are running Apache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076752/how-to-force-apache-to-use-manually-pre-compressed-gz-file-of-css-and-js-files

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/212684/79485

Comment: However, actually, what is an alternative to compressing files for you when you do "local compress"? You should change the title of the question, probably.